# Keras dense layer input shape mismatch

Tags: neural-network, keras

I try to construct the following neural network:

```
img_rows = 63
img_cols= 494
img_channels = 1

nb_classes = 12
nb_positions = 13

conv_filters = 16
kernel_size = (3, 3)
pool_size = 2
time_dense_size = 32
rnn_size = 512
minibatch_size = 32
act = 'relu'

input_shape = (img_channels, img_rows, img_cols)

input_data = Input(name='the_input', shape=input_shape, dtype='float32')
inner = Conv2D(conv_filters, kernel_size, padding='same', activation=act, kernel_initializer='he_normal', name='conv1', data_format="channels_first")(input_data)
inner = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(pool_size, pool_size), name='max1', data_format="channels_first")(inner)
inner = Conv2D(conv_filters, kernel_size, padding='same', activation=act, kernel_initializer='he_normal', name='conv2', data_format="channels_first")(inner)
inner = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(pool_size, pool_size), name='max2', data_format="channels_first")(inner)

#"inner" shape here: TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(16),Dimension(15), Dimension(123)])

conv_to_rnn_dims = (img_rows // (pool_size ** 2), (img_cols // (pool_size ** 2)) * conv_filters)
inner = Reshape(target_shape=conv_to_rnn_dims, name='reshape')(inner)
inner = Dense(time_dense_size, activation=act, name='dense1')(inner)

gru_1 = GRU(rnn_size, return_sequences=True, kernel_initializer='he_normal', name='gru1')(inner)
gru_1b = GRU(rnn_size, return_sequences=True, go_backwards=True, kernel_initializer='he_normal', name='gru1_b')(inner)
gru1_merged = add([gru_1, gru_1b])
gru_2 = GRU(rnn_size, return_sequences=True, kernel_initializer='he_normal', name='gru2')(gru1_merged)
gru_2b = GRU(rnn_size, return_sequences=True, go_backwards=True, kernel_initializer='he_normal', name='gru2_b')(gru1_merged)

inner = Dense(nb_classes+1, kernel_initializer='he_normal', name='dense2')(concatenate([gru_2, gru_2b]))
y_pred = Activation('softmax', name='softmax')(inner)
```

However, in case of the two Dense layers I got error messages like this:

```
Dimensions must be equal, but are 15 and 32 for 'dense1_12/add' (op: 'Add') with input shapes: [?,15,32], [1,32,1].
```

I cannot interpret this message; isn't Dense layers' node numbers are independent of the previous layers and free to define? What is not passing here?

Addition: the whole error message is:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-110-844e7f2bb4a0> in <module>()
----> 1 inner = Dense(time_dense_size, activation=act, name='dense1')(inner)

/home/dsshow/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.pyc in __call__(self, inputs, **kwargs)
    601 
    602             # Actually call the layer, collecting output(s), mask(s), and shape(s).
--> 603             output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
    604             output_mask = self.compute_mask(inputs, previous_mask)
    605 

/home/dsshow/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/layers/core.pyc in call(self, inputs)
    843         output = K.dot(inputs, self.kernel)
    844         if self.use_bias:
--> 845             output = K.bias_add(output, self.bias)
    846         if self.activation is not None:
    847             output = self.activation(output)

/home/dsshow/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.pyc in bias_add(x, bias, data_format)
   3578         if data_format == 'channels_first':
   3579             if len(bias_shape) == 1:
-> 3580                 x += reshape(bias, (1, bias_shape[0], 1))
   3581             else:
   3582                 x += reshape(bias, (1, bias_shape[1], bias_shape[0]))

/home/dsshow/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.pyc in binary_op_wrapper(x, y)
    819       if not isinstance(y, sparse_tensor.SparseTensor):
    820         y = ops.convert_to_tensor(y, dtype=x.dtype.base_dtype, name="y")
--> 821       return func(x, y, name=name)
    822 
    823   def binary_op_wrapper_sparse(sp_x, y):

/home/dsshow/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.pyc in add(x, y, name)
     71     A `Tensor`. Has the same type as `x`.
     72   """
---> 73   result = _op_def_lib.apply_op("Add", x=x, y=y, name=name)
     74   return result
     75 

/home/dsshow/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.pyc in apply_op(self, op_type_name, name, **keywords)
    766         op = g.create_op(op_type_name, inputs, output_types, name=scope,
    767                          input_types=input_types, attrs=attr_protos,
--> 768                          op_def=op_def)
    769         if output_structure:
    770           outputs = op.outputs

/home/dsshow/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.pyc in create_op(self, op_type, inputs, dtypes, input_types, name, attrs, op_def, compute_shapes, compute_device)
   2336                     original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
   2337     if compute_shapes:
-> 2338       set_shapes_for_outputs(ret)
   2339     self._add_op(ret)
   2340     self._record_op_seen_by_control_dependencies(ret)

/home/dsshow/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.pyc in set_shapes_for_outputs(op)
   1717       shape_func = _call_cpp_shape_fn_and_require_op
   1718 
-> 1719   shapes = shape_func(op)
   1720   if shapes is None:
   1721     raise RuntimeError(

/home/dsshow/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.pyc in call_with_requiring(op)
   1667 
   1668   def call_with_requiring(op):
-> 1669     return call_cpp_shape_fn(op, require_shape_fn=True)
   1670 
   1671   _call_cpp_shape_fn_and_require_op = call_with_requiring

/home/dsshow/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.pyc in call_cpp_shape_fn(op, input_tensors_needed, input_tensors_as_shapes_needed, debug_python_shape_fn, require_shape_fn)
    608     res = _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl(op, input_tensors_needed,
    609                                   input_tensors_as_shapes_needed,
--> 610                                   debug_python_shape_fn, require_shape_fn)
    611     if not isinstance(res, dict):
    612       # Handles the case where _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl calls unknown_shape(op).

/home/dsshow/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.pyc in _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl(op, input_tensors_needed, input_tensors_as_shapes_needed, debug_python_shape_fn, require_shape_fn)
    674       missing_shape_fn = True
    675     else:
--> 676       raise ValueError(err.message)
    677 
    678   if missing_shape_fn:

ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 15 and 32 for 'dense1_17/add' (op: 'Add') with input shapes: [?,15,32], [1,32,1].
```

Comment: would you put the entire error message